# How to reset/restart backbone application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm building a little quiz game using backbone.js

Once you get to the end of the quiz you have the option to start again.

How can I achieve this? I've tried recalling the initialize function, as well as the first function that gets fired when you start the game.  This is just returning errors.  The two calls are success but a subsequent function for rending each question is failing.

I think I need to empty my model/collection.  This is my first outing with Backbone, I'm still trying to get my head around how every works.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the backbone router (don't forget to [start](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start) it):

So in your game view, you'd have an event which triggered when the start again button was clicked. This event would trigger a function which would redirect the user to a newgame route. You could also setup a function in the router to close your old view. This is important to [avoid zombie views](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/)

e.g. view

```
//initialize code
//...
events: {
  'click .startAgainButton':'restart'
}

restart: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = '#/new_game';
}
//rest of view code...
```

e.g. router

```
//router code
routes: {
    "new_game":"reset"
},

trackView: function (next) {
    if (this.current) this.current.close();
    this.current = next;
},

//kill zombie views
close: function () {
  this.undelegateEvents();
  this.$el.off();
  this.$el.children().remove();
},

reset: function() {
    this.trackView(new View());
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response.  I've not used any routes in my quiz application.  I'm not sure if taking this approach is going to mean re-factoring the existing code.